# Can static class contains instance initialization block?

Tags: java, initialization-block

While reading Java I came across one question:

Can a static class contains *instance initialization block*?

Comment: Static classes are not [tag:inner-classes], by definition.

Answer (score 1):

Static (or nested) classes can have both instance and static initialization blocks.

Consider a nested class as

> a *top-level* class that has been nested in another top-level class for packaging convenience.
>   <sup><sub>[The Java Tutorials > Nested Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)</sub></sup>

On the other hand, inner classes can't have a static initialization block. No static content is allowed within them.